# Java Byte, what happens when trying to fit a greater number than 127

Tags: java, int, byte

I am new to Java but I have been coding in other languages for quite some time. Today I started looking into Java and I noticed an Exception that seems interesting.

When I declare a byte variable and try to store a number smaller than -128 or greater than 127, compiler gives me an error saying

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte"

Now I know exactly why I can't store lets say 130 in byte for example, but why is the compiler trying to convert from int to byte if I try to assign the value to byte ?

Comment: All numbers are either `int` or `double` by default, and you didn't say otherwise.

Comment: You _can_ convert from `int` to `byte` if you do so explicitly: `byte b = (byte)130`.

Comment: By the way, to avoid confusion, what you saw is a compilation error, not an `Exception`.  Exceptions are things that get thrown only at run time.

Answer (score 0):

A byte has 8 bits, and its range is -2<sup>8-1</sup> to 2<sup>8-1</sup>-1 i.e  -128 to 127.

This is based on the following equation:

-2<sup>n-1</sup> to -2<sup>n-1</sup>-1,

where n is the number of bits.

You are using values out of range, so a larger data type is needed, for example `int`.

If you cross the range of particular type, then it is automatically considered an `int` data type.

Comment: This site doesn't accept TeX math formulas, but you can still get exponents by using HTML: `<sup>...</sup>`

Comment: Thank you. I am out of touch with this site so don't know about this.